# creating regex for some urls for my robot.txt

Tags: regex, url, regex-group

I have five url patterns for which i want to make some regex so that i can put it in my robot.txt for noindexing.

for both this pages i need two different regex
Url patterns are like:
https:// example.com/[varying-data]-addiction-treatmnet
https:// example.com/[varying-data]-addiction-treatmnet/thank-you

Answer (score 0):

As you have everytime the same url with only one varying part, you can use a simple regex like

`https:\/\/example.com\/.*-addiction-treatmnet`

and

`https:\/\/example.com\/.*-addiction-treatmnet/thank-you`

or as list:

`(https:\/\/example.com\/.*-addiction-treatmnet)|(https:\/\/example.com\/.*-addiction-treatmnet/thank-you)`

Comment: can i use something like array for those addiction-treatment word 
if i have four or five and i want only one regex

Comment: yes, you can write it like this: `(regex1)|(regex2)|(regex3)`. (see edited answer)